# Did Augusto del Noce coin the phrase "the crisis of modernity"?

Tags: italian-language

I first heard the phrase "the crisis of modernity" in a lecture on neo-Nazism. The phrase "Crisis of Modernity" doesn't have a Wikipedia page but [Augusto del Noce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusto_Del_Noce), who wrote a book called *The Crisis of Modernity,* does.

Comment: Noce clearly didn't coin it in his 2015 book because there were earlier books such as *Nature and the Crisis of Modernity: A Critique of Contemporary Discourse on Managing the Earth* by Raymond Albert Rogers (1994). This does make me wonder what research you have done; you are normally supposed to explain when asking a question to prevent unnecessary duplication of effort.

Comment: @StuartF (1) The 2015 book is a translation of an Italian book from 1989, which predates *Nature and the Crisis of Modernity*. (2) What level of research does *this* site require?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book [*The Crisis of Modernity*](https://www.mqup.ca/crisis-of-modernity--the-products-9780773544437.php) (McGill-Queen's University Press, 2015) is a translation of *Secolarizzazione e crisi della modernità*, which was published in 1989. If that is the first publication in which Del Noce used the phrase "crisi della modernità", that he did not coin that phrase. Del Noce used the phrase "la crisi dell’idea di modernità" ("the crisis of the idea of modernity") in an essay entitled "Eric Voegelin e la crisi dell’idea di modernità" (see the "References" in Thomassen & Forlenza).

This phrase predates the famous essay [The Three Waves of Modernity](https://archive.org/details/LeoStrauss3WavesOfModernityocr) by [Leo Strauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Strauss) (1899–1973), a much more influential political philosopher. The essay was published posthumously in *Political Philosophy: Six Essays by Leo Strauss* in 1975. In this essay, Strauss described Oswald Spengler's *The Decline of the West* as "a powerful document to the crisis of modernity".

But the phrase "crisis of modernity" or certain variations of it can be found elsewhere.

- In the title of the book [*Politics and the crisis of modernity* by Norman Jacobson](https://www.worldcat.org/title/233031462), published in 1967.
- The phrase "superare la crisi della modernità" appears in a Google Books snippet view of [*Totalità*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Totalit%C3%A0/OB0ble0vWJAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22crisi+della+modernit%C3%A0%22&dq=%22crisi+della+modernit%C3%A0%22&printsec=frontcover), published in 1934.
- The phrase "long crisis of modernity" appears in a Google Books snippet view of page 488 of [*Political Science Quarterly* published in 1931](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Political_Science_Quarterly/0UoUAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22crisis+of+modernity%22&dq=%22crisis+of+modernity%22&printsec=frontcover) .

Based on this it appears that Augusto Del Noce did not coin the phrase but it is not clear who did.

**References**

- Rosboch, Michele: [Del Noce, la crisi della modernità](https://www.lavocedeltempo.com/Cultura/Del-Noce-la-crisi-della-modernita), *La Voce del Tiempo*, 09/11/2017 .
- Thomassen, Bjorn; Forlenza, Rosario: [Voegelin’s Impact on the Italian Response to Modernity: The Parallel Lives and Works of Augusto del Noce and Eric Voegelin](https://voegelinview.com/voegelins-impact-italian-response-modernity-parallel-life-works-augusto-del-noce-eric-voegelin/), VoegelinView [website of the [Eric Voegelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Voegelin) Society], 26.11.2014.